# Understanding the NumPy's arctan2 documentation

Tags: python, numpy, math

I am reading the [`arctan2`'s documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) of Numpy, where I came across this:

```
    x1        x2     arctan2(x1,x2)

1) +/- 0      +0        +/- 0
2) +/- 0      -0        +/- pi
3) > 0      +/-inf     +0 / +pi
4) < 0      +/-inf     -0 / -pi
5) +/-inf    +inf     +/- (pi/4)
6) +/-inf    -inf     +/- (3*pi/4)

Note that +0 and -0 are distinct floating point numbers, as are +inf and -inf.
```

I do know how the signed radian value is calculated and what kind of answer supposed to be outputed. Kind of like this:

[image: arctan]

What I don't understand is, what kind of meaning does the `0`, `π` and `inf` supposed to bring in the documentation? What kind of values should they present?

Take example for number `2)` of the documentation:

Let say `x1` (or the y-coordinate) is 5 and the `x2` (or the x-coordinate) is -5. The result by `arctan2` would be somewhere between `π/2` and `π`. How does this correspond to the value of `π` in above's documentation?

Comment: (5, -5) is not in that table, is it?

Answer (score 0):

That table only addresses the special cases for the unusual float values of signed zero or infinity. `0.0` and `-0.0` are separate floating point values, though they compare the same. `float("inf")` (also known accessible as `np.inf` in numpy) is also a specific float value, as is its negation (which can be spelled `float("-inf")`, `-float("inf")` or `-np.inf`).

The `arctan2` function is well defined, even for these obscure float values, and the table summarizes how it works. The second rule on the table says that `arctan2(0.0, -0.0)` is `pi` and `arctan2(-0.0, -0.0)` is `-pi`. The results for the infinite values are pretty straight forward. For the signed zeros, it makes sense if you think about `0.0` being an infinitesimal positive number, and `-0.0` being an infinitesimal negative number.

The chart doesn't have anything to say about the value of `arctan2(5, -5)`, since that isn't a special case. As it happens, that call happens to give the same result as `arctan(np.inf, -np.inf)` which is shown on the table as `3*pi/4`, but that's just a coincidence of which numbers you picked.